# group by with all fields django

Tags: django, group-by, group-concat

I want to run 2 queries in django, I am using mysql, Please help me

first one

```
SELECT * FROM `invitations` 
WHERE post_id = 19215 GROUP BY (user_id)
```

it is not group by from user_id

```
   data = Invitations.objects.filter(post_id=19215).annotate(user_id=Count('user_id'))
```

now i have add value

```
data = Invitations.objects.values('user_id').filter(post_id=19215).annotate(user_id=Count('user_id'))
```

it return me not all fields select *

```
data = Invitations.objects.values('user_id', 'xyz').filter(post_id=19215).annotate(user_id=Count('user_id'))
```

it group by user_id and xyz

Please give me solution

and second is

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(interview_mode) FROM invitations WHERE post_id = 19215 GROUP BY (user_id)
```

Comment: Are you using postgresql right? The columns which you selects should be added to group by. If you try to run raw query in postgresql you won't able to run that successfully unless you add column into group by which you keep in select. It is because columns which are in select can have different values and those need to be in grouped.

Comment: I am using mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this:

```
query= "SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(interview_mode) 
FROM invitations WHERE post_id = 19215 
GROUP BY (user_id)"

data = Model.objects.raw(query)
```